# View bounces when sending through general email (not CiviMail)

Tags: email

Is there a way to view or be informed about bounces sent through CiviCRM other than through the CiviMail component (i.e. send now, transactional emails, etc.)? I discovered that a contact who should have been receiving important emails about an event had an incorrect email address and so wasn't receiving the emails. Neither were we getting notified that there was a problem. I'd like to avoid this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my own answer. Our bounces@... address is set up as a catch-all, so bounces (or other badly addressed email) come to it, but CiviMail only processes bounces from emails sent through that component. Other emails are sitting in the inbox of the bounces@ account, waiting to be read, or forwarded through judicious use of a filter.

Leaving this question for posterity.

Comment: Also discovered that failure notices were being flagged as spam, so they were not sitting in the inbox when the Civi cron connected to collect the mail. (We're using a G-Suite email account as our bounce address.)

Comment: You know you can set a filter to ensure nothing is flagged as spam?

Comment: Yes, I took care of that once I realized what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

Philip - there is also this [Extension](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional) - **Transactional Mail - Bounce and Tracking Handler** - that Fuzion made to give better visibility of the non-civi-mail emails which you might find useful

Comment: Thanks, Pete. Already found it! It is useful, but I'm wanting a more immediate notice when an email has bounced.